# jquery automatic image reload on src attribute update?

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have an html string like so :

```
var string = '<div><img src="foo/bar" /></div>';
```

and I select the image part of it like so :

```
var $img = $(string).find('img');
```

and then I change the 'src' attribute :

```
$img.attr('src', 'foo2/bar2');
```

Does this trigger an automatic AJAX get request at the new 'src'? I'm getting a rogue GET error in my code that goes away when I comment out the line above, but maybe it's coming from somewhere else.

If this is in fact coming from Jquery, is there a way to turn off or block the AJAX request? I've tried .stopPropogation() without any luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case that `$img` is a real dom elemnt (exists in your html) - a get reqest will fire. 

if `$img` is not you won't trigger a get request but you can still trigger it by:

```
$img[0].src = '/foo/bar'
```

[image: example]

the only way you can stop a browser from rendering images is by stopping it:

```
if(window.stop !== undefined)
  window.stop();    
else if(document.execCommand !== undefined)
  document.execCommand("Stop", false);
```

Comment: thanks @sagivo! in fact the string in question is definitely not in the DOM but is a string of html copied (as a string) from the DOM. But the get call really seems to be coming from exactly this place in the code...

Comment: This will no longer work, sadly. I got requests on any use of $.find() or subsequent changes to img src.