# Change src attribute for image without AJAX get request

Tags: jquery

This is a continuation of another question : [jquery automatic image reload on src attribute update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352499/jquery-automatic-image-reload-on-src-attribute-update)

Using the following code, I get an AJAX GET call for the new image src location, even when the image doesn't seem to be in the DOM :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function(){
            $('#button').click( function(){
                var $container = $('#container');
                var string = $container.html();
                string = string.toString();
              var $string = $(string);
                $string.attr('src', 'foo');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='container'><img src='pointIcon.png'/></div>
        <button id='button'>Go!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on how to manipulate $string object without triggering the AJAX call? Have tried .toString(), .stopPropogation(), with no luck so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try wrapping it in <div style='display:none'> so that it's not visible when you parse the string into DOM elements, this might prevent the browser from loading the image.  If not, you'll have to manipulate it using string manipulation, not jQuery, because $(string) will create DOM elements for you which is causing the image to be created and then request the image

Comment: ok that's really useful! so even though the selected html is not in the DOM tree it's still in the DOM somehow?

Comment: when you call $(...) it adds it to the DOM

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var string=$("#container img");
string.attr('src', 'foo');
```

instead of:

```
var string = $container.html();
string = string.toString();
var $string = $(string);
$string.attr('src', 'foo');
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/igitox/1/edit

Comment: thanks @Pablo Martinez but running this code still triggers a GET call - you won't see it in jsfiddle or jsbin, you have to paste it into an html file and open it directly

Comment: I think if the new src of the image is not loaded, a GET call is needed to load the image... I'm not sure of this

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function(){
            $('#button').click( function(){
                var image = $('#container img');
                image.attr('src', 'foo');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'><img src='pointIcon.png'/></div>
    <button id='button'>Go!</button>
</body>
</html>
```